# Как в Django проекте в Docker корректно установить и запустить Celery c RabbitMQ?

Tags: python, django, docker, rabbitmq, celery

Всем привет! Проект на Django. Использую Docker. Нужно установить и подключить к проекту Celery и RabbitMQ.

Dockerfile

```
 FROM python:3.7-slim

 ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
 ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

 WORKDIR /code

 COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /code/
 RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system

 COPY . /code/
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
        - .:/code
    ports:
        - 8000:8000
```

Подскажите, как это сделать?

Comment: Добавить в docker-compose.yml нужный сервис.

Comment: @zalex подскажите как правильно это сделать.

Answer (score 3):

С RabbitMQ все просто, готовый образ есть на [докерхабе](https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq). Нужно лишь добавить сервис в докер композ.

```
  rabbit:
    restart: always
    image: "rabbitmq:3-management"
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_NODENAME: "rabbit@localhost"
      RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE: "SWQOKODSQALRPCLNMEQG"
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: "rabbitmq"
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: "rabbitmq"
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST: "/"
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"
```

15672 - это порт веб интерфейса для менеджмента кролика, логин и пароль указаны в переменных окружения. Я задаю куки вручную для будущей кластеризации, а имя ноды, чтобы хранить задачи кролика на диске и вслучае миграции сервера восстановить их.

Теперь достаточно указать в настройках дажанго в параметре `CELERY_BROKER_URL` значение `amqp://rabbitmq:rabbitmq@rabbit:5672`. Сервисы докера могут взаимодействовать по сети используя имя сервиса, докер сам транслирует имя сервиса в нужный IP адрес в случае если настройки сети для композа дефолтные.

С celery немного иначе, так как селери является пакетом пайтона и интегрируется в джангу, то можно не создавать отдельный сервис для него. Мне же нужно было чтобы я мог остановить разбор задач без остановки сайта, таким образом сайт принимает новые запросы и может генерировать новые задачи, которые скапливаются в кролике, а как только я запущу сервис с Celery, то эти задачи начнут выполняться. Это актуально в моей практике, так как задачи работают с эластиком на котором иногда проводят манипуляции с индексами и в это время отправлять что-то в эластик нельзя.

Поэтому для сельдерея создан отдельный сервис

```
  celery:
    restart: always
    build: .
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ./source/:/app
    environment:
      DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "{APP}.settings.docker"
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 15G
        reservations:
          memory: 10G
    ports:
      - "5555:5555"
    command: bash -c "
      rm -rf /tmp/celery*.pid &
      python -m celery multi start --app={APP} --pidfile=/tmp/%n.pid --logfile=/app/logs/celery/%n.log 4 -c 4 -Q:1 dispatch -Q:2 process_item -Q:3 network -c:4 1 -Q:4 celery -E &&
      python -m celery -A {APP} beat --pidfile=/tmp/celerybeat.pid -l info --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler --detach &&
      python -m celery flower -A {APP} --conf=/app/{APP}/settings/flowerconfig.py --address=0.0.0.0"
    links:
      - rabbit
    depends_on:
      - rabbit
```

В блоке command описан набор команд, я храню pid процессов селери в /tmp, чтобы очищать их в ручную или чтобы они очищались автоматически, так как сталкивался с тем что после перезапуска сервиса, pid файлы процессов не уничтожались, что приводило к крашу при запуске работников. Последней командой запускается flower - это веб интерфейс для мониторинга задач селери. Также я ставлю ограничение на количество памяти для селери применить которое можно добавив флаг `--compatibility` для docker-compose при выполнении команды up.

`docker-compose --compatibility up -d celery`

В файле настроек для flower также задается url брокера

`broker_api = 'http://rabbitmq:rabbitmq@rabbit:15672/api/'`

Важно! Никогда не используйте дефолтные логины и пароли! Учитывайте, что в моем примере порты сервисов менеджмента торчат наружу. Ну и при изменении кода для тасок перезапускать нужно 2 сервиса: сайт и celery.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за развернутый ответ! Но я джун и мне требуется еще помощь в этом вопросе. В книге по которой я сейчас изучаю Джанго указано, что после установки селери и раппиб нужно создать файл celery.py в каталоге с settings.py следующего содержания: 'import os from celery import Celery # set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program. os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myshop.settings') app = Celery('myshop') app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY') app.autodiscover_tasks()' но импорт celery выдает ошибку no module

Comment: как дальше создавать таски и тп ? Создаю файл celery.py, но from celery import Celery сразу выдает ошибку, хотя Pipfile содержит установленную celery .  Я джун и в Джанго и в докере, и с селери впервые сталкиваюсь. Нужна помощь. :)

Comment: Тогда это неформат «вопрос-ответ», а обучение конкретной технологии, так как интегрировать сельдерей это только начало длинного путешествия. Если import celery не работает, значит нет пакета селери.

Answer (score 0):

Понимаю, что уже довольно много времени с создания вопроса прошло, но, надеюсь, что данная информация кому-либо пригодится. Если вы сейчас изучаете вопрос интеграции Celery в собственный (или не собственный) Django-проект, то могу посоветовать статью (перевод статьи автора Michael Herman) на хабре - вот [ссылка](https://habr.com/ru/company/otus/blog/503380/); и соответствующий репозиторий - [ссылка](https://github.com/testdrivenio/django-celery). Ясно, что там в примерах используется Redis как брокер и бэк для сельдерея, но это всё помогло мне интегрировать сельдерей, когда я с ним столкнулся первый раз (совсем недавно), и далее просто переключить на RabbitMQ, добавив соответствующий сервис в docker-compose, а Redis остался под кэш Django.